# Monitoring directory in finderSync extension failed to work

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I have developed a Cocoa application with a FinderSync extension through which a newly created directory is monitored.

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes when I activate the Drive and Dropbox extension (from Settings > Preferences > Extensions ), my application stops monitoring the directory for which it is intended.

I have searched for the solution but haven't found anything.

Do I need to register my application with an OS X service?